# Formatting a textarea(email) before sending it

Tags: php, css

I'm very new at PHP/CSS and programming in general for that matter.

I want to change the formatting of a text in a textarea like one would do here, for example when adding the tags "Code Sample" for a highlighted text it will indent it or when setting it as bold it will bold it.

The purpose of this would be preformatting an e-mail before sending it.

I'm pretty sure this is a vast subject so I'm not looking for an explanation as much as a few links to some tutorials. I'm having trouble find some with Google since I don't even know what to search for exactly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use any of the Editor for this purpose.

like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/),[Tiny MCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) just Google it you can find lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for code I'd recommend [Ace](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about). For common text editing and formatting, I'd use [TinyMce](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Both are very simple to use and have good interface and development support.

Comment: TinyMCE looks pretty handy. Thanks.